# Helm template - integer value is always rendered as 0

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I see somewhat strange behaviour of helm template:

My tpl function does this:

```
{{- define "spark-k8s-application.maxExecutors" -}}
...
  {{- printf "%d" .Values.application.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors | int }}
```

Later I use it for a label:

```
labels:
    spark-executors-max: {{ include "spark-k8s-application.maxExecutors" . | quote }}
```

But whatever number I put in my input parameters, it is always rendered as *"0"*
How could I render the correct integer value?

Comment: Does it work inside the inner template to just use `.Values...maxExecutors` without any of the surrounding type-conversion logic?  What is the actual value you're configuring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in parenthesis and operation order.

This expression works as expected:

```
{{- printf "%d" (.Values.application.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors | int) }}
```

Looks like you have to be very explicit about order of operations in go templates.